# archivo .py no existe en cmd ( Windows) de django, como lo agrego?

Tags: python, django

acabo de instalar lo que es bitnami 2.0.4 en su ultima version y tengo un problema al querer crear un nuevo proyecto, al hacer el comando

django-admin.py startproject myproyect

al principio me aparecia un error de que no existia el archivo django-admin

y me abria una ventana donde tenia que seleccionar algun paquete para abrir el archivo, probe con seleccionar el archivo python para poder ejecutar el comando, pero no me resulto, y ahora me aparece esto...

[image: esta es lo que me muestra]

Comment: Ya intentaste de esta manera: django-admin startproject myproject?

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75718/discussion-on-question-by-lun-archivo-py-no-existe-en-cmd-windows-de-django).

Answer (score 1):

El error esta en que estas ingresando mal el subcomando `startproject` y estas colocando `startproyect`

Comment: pero ya corregi eso, osea en la imagen misma se ve que el error persiste

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer te hace falta configurar la variable de configuración [`DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#designating-the-settings), puedes encontrar una ayuda extra de como hacerlo en esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12854946/2363144)